# SQL Server - Prefix and zero padding ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2014

To be quick, here's my problem, I have been trying to search StackOverflow for the answer but I can't find a satisfactory answer.

**I have an InvoiceHeader table with columns (simplified) :**

```
InvoiceID   : Int - PK Identity(1,1)
InvoiceDate : date
CustomerID  : Int - FK to Customer table
```

Etc...

I will frequently display information about Invoice to users.
When I display the invoice number to the users, I need to **add prefix and zero padding** the InvoiceID.

**For example :**

```
InvoiceID : 1 
Invoice Number : INV0000001
```

My question is, should I make a **BRAND NEW** PERSISTED COMPUTED column in the `InvoiceHeader` table to save the formatted invoice number like this :

```
InvoiceNumber AS 'INV' + RIGHT('000000'+cast(InvoiceID as varchar(7)),7)
```

or should I select the `InvoiceID` and process it into `INV0000001` at runtime from my application?

My dilemma :

- If I add a new PERSISTED COMPUTED column (i.e InvoiceNumber) then I can make a Non Clustered Index at InvoiceNumber which will help when there is query with InvoiceNumber in WHERE clause. But this will still need covering index or include index to get other column's value. Also another plus is I don't have to "format" it to become INV0000001 everytime I need to display it.
- If I format InvoiceID to become INV0000001 at SELECT QUERY from my app, it will be too much "chore", everytime I want to display InvoiceNumber I have to format it. But i won't need another column which basically have the same value with InvoiceID with some prefix and zero padding.
- Invoice number will be used by users for searching, for example : find me an invoice with number like '1234'+'%'. If this is done to InvoiceID (integer column) it will make an IMPLICIT conversion, will it make the query slower? Will the PK index still be used by query plan?

---

**EDIT** :
Thinking about lots of places where I will have to manually format Invoice Number everytime I need it (if I don't use computed column), I'm now almost confinced to go with **Esperento57's solution** :

**Make 2 new column :**

```
InvoiceID      : int identity (PK)
Prefix         : char(3) --> INV, etc
InvoiceNumber  : Prefix + RIGHT('000000'+cast(InvoiceID as varchar(7)),7)
```

But I won't make PK include Prefix because InvoiceID is `identity` so it's unique by itself.

I'm also still considering @Matt's point about *separation of concerns* too, because it makses sense.

Comment: An other option: create a brand new column and use a insert trigger to fill that column.

Comment: I think if I end up adding a new column, a persisted computed column is better in this case because computed colum will guarantee the value, also it is set and forget. While trigger is another sql statement so it will be slower than computed. Cmiiw*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposition for your columns :

- InvoiceID : integer not null with autoincrement (sequence are not necessary, SQL Server do the job)
- Prefix: varchar(10) not null FK on PREFIXTABLE
- InvoiceID and Prefix are the primary key
- InvoiceNumber : computed and persisted column = Prefix + RIGHT('0000000'+ InvoiceID,7)
- Add an index on InvoiceNumber

With my proposition you can :

1. Change prefix if necessary
2. You have integrity on prefix
3. You have integrity on your complet key and keep the really primary key
4. You have not to recalculate the complete key
5. In case of data recovery, you can make jumps of sequences to your keys or simply choose another prefix
6. You can add a description into your PREFIX table for explain your prefix (for futur developper by example)

Comment: good idea on making prefix reference a a prefix table.

But why we have to include the Prefix in Primary key?
Since InvoiceID is identity, it should be unique so there won't be 2 Prefixes with same InvoiceID.

Comment: Its a choice, prefix are not necessary into your key its true. But you give INV0000001 to you client. And if someone modify your prefix into your table (by error), you lose your key. But if your multiple key are used as FK, he cant modify your key. Other problem: in case of data recovery you want may be have the same id but with a different prefix

Comment: If my response satisfy you, you can up for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it as a numeric value in the database and format it, this will stop you unnecessarily storing data that has no value and will improve the performance of queries. You can apply the format at a low level in your application if that cuts down on the number of places you need to format, but depending on the complexity of your app you're unlikely to need to write this formatting logic more than once anyway.

### Edit

There are some valid points in the other answers, e.g. the point about missing numbers may or may not be important to you - only you know if that's relevant.

The issue of changing the prefix in the future I'd be wary of unless you know it's a concrete requirement now. There are various ways of retrofitting a change to your prefix, whether you're storing it in the DB, generating it in a view or in the UI/business layer. This is one of those things that I'd suggest to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html)!

NB. Martin Fowler makes a very good point in the above article about the distinction between building presumptive features and building extensible software. That's the important measure to always use when considering designs around these types of issues - do the minimum you can to ensure you have extension points, but only implement the features you know you need.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this option but I will need to format the InvoiceID to INV0000001 in lots of place. Like reports, sales return module, AR module, etc. Maybe it is OK if I make a scalar valued function in the database with the prefix and InvoiceID parameter and call it every time I need to display invoice number? Or this will make the query slower when selecting thousands of invoice rows?

Comment: So it becomes an architectural decision then, if it makes sense to do the formatting in a database view the might be ok, alternatively you could do it in a common business layer, etc. This is what I meant by having the formatting applied at a low level depending on where it's required but also making sure that you're [separating your concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should really separate internal `ID`, which is a primary key and is used to identify a record, from a string that user sees.

End-user should never see IDs generated by `IDENTITY`, because there easily can be gaps.

So, I'd have two normal columns: `int InvoiceID` and `char(10) InvoiceNumber`. Yes, there will be a separate method to generate a next Invoice Number. In SQL Server 2014 I'd use [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) object with `NO CACHE` option for it.

When you separate internal IDs from the user-visible Invoice Numbers you make it easy to make changes to the format of these numbers in the future. For example, in two years the finance department may decide that it wants to introduce another prefix `ABC000001`. Obviously, all existing historical invoices should preserve their numbers. With a separate column for Invoice Number there is no problem. With a computed column you'll have a problem.

Comment: afaik sequence also leave gaps if the insert failed.
Changing Prefix can be solved with Esperento57's proposition below.

Comment: My main point - don't show your internal `ID` to the end user. You may need to change `ID` at some point, but historical Invoice Number can't be changed. Today your invoice numbers are numeric, tomorrow your company is bought by another company and the whole structure of invoices can be totally different.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the formula for calculating invoicenumber,

```
InvoiceNumber  : Prefix + RIGHT('000000'+cast(InvoiceID as varchar(7)),7)
```

Here gap beween invoicenumber do not matter.

Then I would keep onlyInvoiceID.While displaying I will format invoicenumber in said manner either in low level or proc itself.
when User will search for invoice number then I remove prefix and cast it into int variable.

Then I will search on invoiceID column.

But If Prefix may change and  there should not be GAP between invoicenumber then,

i) Keeping Prefix in same table is bad idea.

ii) Also calculation of invoicenumber will change because you have to maintain continuity.

> But I won't make PK include Prefix because InvoiceID is identity so
>   it's unique by itself.

It depend.Sure according to me also Prefix is out of question.but InvoiceID can be PK+CI or only PK or Only identity or only CI.

you hv to examine each option.

Comment: Yes, after rethink it yesterday, I plan to make InvoiceNumber a persisted computed column but without any index. 
I'll use InvoiceID in queries since it's clustered index and have same value with InvoiceNumber.

I end up making InvoiceNumber because there's too many places that will need formatting InvoiceID to InvoiceNumber.

InvoiceNumber sequence is not important in my case. 
I even use same table for Sales Return (with negative Qty column, Prefix will be used to identify Sales Invoice and Sales Return).
I thought to encode it so it will be more untraceable but don't feel I need to.

Comment: *by the way, what is "low level"? is it mean making a function in my app that return the formatted string?